# Recursively dump the contents of an aggregate structure (Collection, Array) in Java

Tags: java

This is my very first question on Stackoverflow, so please bear with me if you find anything nonsensical in my very first post. FYI that I've gone through the SO FAQ and I'm aware of its various policies. You see, I'm a guy that has heavily worked with languages such as PHP, Perl, Python, ROR and recently I "context-switched" to Java EE. You see, several of the languages that I've worked on had a construct that enabled me to recursively dump the contents of an aggregate structure without a for/foreach/for..in loop

For example,

```
a = Any composite Data structure
```

PHP has

```
var_dump() and print_r()
```

Perl has

```
Data::Dumper
```

ROR has

```
PrettyPrint
```

and Python has

```
pprint module
```

.

So my question goes,

Is there an equivalent of any of these in the Java universe ?  I find it very convenient when I used to work in any of these languages (PHP/Perl/Python/ROR) to dump the contents of an composite data-structure to examine how it looks and then process it further (or decide on how to process it further)

Thanks for your time and apologies if my post overlooks any SO rules.

Comment: 1) Welcome to SO.  2) Regarding your SO etiquette, the only thing you did wrong was to mention so much about being new to SO. Be direct and to the point with your question - when someone else searches for the same topic, they don't care about your life story. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `java.util` collections have `toString()` that will recursively dump out the details of the list / set / map etc.  This requires that the objects stored in the collection have useful `toString()`s defined.

It breaks down for arrays however, because Java doesn't have a useful default `toString()` for an array.  If you know you're dealing with an array, then you can use the `Arrays.deepToString()` utility method (see [guido's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11027222/1212960) for more detail).

For example, this code:

```
final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
final List<String> nested = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz");

map.put("given", "Arthur");
map.put("family", "Dent");
map.put("nested", nested);

System.out.println(map);
```

Produces this:

```
{nested=[foo, bar, baz], given=Arthur, family=Dent}
```

Comment: Ok, this sums it up your answer and the above one. Not sure about which one should I green-check :) Thanks a lot for replying.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the utility static methods found in `java.util.Arrays` class:

```
public static String toString(Object[] a)
ie: String dump = Arrays.toString(array);
```

Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array.

If the array contains other arrays as elements, they are converted to strings by the Object.toString() method inherited from Object, which describes their identities rather than their contents.

The value returned by this method is equal to the value that would be returned by Arrays.asList(a).toString(), unless a is null, in which case "null" is returned.

```
public static String deepToString(Object[] a)
ie: String dump = Arrays.deepToString(array);
```

Returns a string representation of the "deep contents" of the specified array. If the array contains other arrays as elements, the string representation contains their contents and so on. This method is designed for converting multidimensional arrays to strings.

The string representation consists of a list of the array's elements, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (a comma followed by a space). Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(Object), unless they are themselves arrays.

In case of colletions, you can use the method toArray():

```
 List<YourObject> list = .....
 YourObject[] array = list.toArray(new YourObject[0]);
 String dump = Arrays.deepToString(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your purpose, which I assume to debug code or explore a complex data structure, **don't print**.

Use a good UI debugger such as the one in IntelliJ or (shudder, please just don't) eclipse. Java has a much more mature and complete set of tools available for developers compared to the other languages you listed (I've also worked in most of those). Php, Perl, etc are primative and for some reason people keep expecting to develop in a simple text editor. Java doesn't work that way (at least not if you want to stay sane or are working on anything bigger than a toy project).

Use a full featured IDE and it's built in debugger.

In the others you listed there isn't a very good option for an IDE and the debugging integration is piss poor at best... This is one of the major advantages to Java in fact.