# Dumping the contents of a java.util.Map - Not working as expected

Tags: java, servlets, collections

I'd like to base this question on the basis of the response posted by @Greg Kopff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027157/recursively-dump-the-contents-of-an-aggregate-structure-collection-array-in-j)

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to DUMP the contents of the Map returned by request.getParameterMap() method to the output.

I'm getting the following weird Map as output(the values of which I believe are the addresses of the object references of either String or String arrays)

```
    {submit=[Ljava.lang.String;@1fe4169, color=[Ljava.lang.String;@178920a,  
         chek_games=[Ljava.lang.String;@bbfa5c, foo=[Ljava.lang.String;@131de9b}
```

I have tried the following code -

```
    public class CoffeeSelect extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Map requestParams = req.getParameterMap();

        resp.getWriter().println(requestParams);
        }

    }
```

The following is my HTML <form>

```
    <form action="SelectCofee.Do" method="post">
     <select id="coffe_color" name="color">
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
     </select>

     <br/><br/>
     <input type="checkbox" id="chek_games" name="chek_games" value="chess" />
     <input type="checkbox" id="chek_games" name="chek_games" value="badminton" />
     <input type="checkbox" id="chek_games" name="chek_games" value="cricket" />

     <input type="hidden" id="foo" name="foo" value="bar" />

     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

How to deference those object references or let me put it this way; Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[L` notation tells that it is the String representation of an `String[]`. HTTP lets you do something like

http://myserver.com/mypage?myparam=firstvalue&myparam=secondvalue....

(think of multi-selection `<select>`)

To allow for this, the parameter Map is not `Map<String, String>` but `Map<String, String[]>` (I do not know if the implementation really uses generics, it is just an explicit representation).

So, to dump the parameters, you need to either.

a) assume you won't get multiple values for the same param; loop for the param names and use `request.getParameter`

b) if you accept multiple values, loop for the param names and serialize the array.

Comment: Oh...I got it. May be i should read up on Collections and Java more. Thank you. Will accept this as the best answer in 5 mins.. i guess it's locked.

Comment: The use of collections was correct, you just guessed wrong the class of the values. But yes, knowing fully a programming language / API requires its effort.

Comment: Yes. I understand and agree with you. I'm more accustomed to Perl/Python/PHP and Rails syntax/semantics and very recently i shifted to a new project that's in J2EE. That's why facing many, innumerable problems with the OO nature of Java..Problem is that the project has already started and I get very less time to study the API ... :( . I programmed in Java some 7 years back but now I'm as clean as a white slate...lol..

Comment: BTW, most Map classes implement `Serializable`. Maybe that is the way to get your dump.